# CSS - trying to move a picture without it unaligned everything else; what are the correct properties?

Tags: html, css

this is the project I am working on

http://codepen.io/willc86/pen/ocqkf

and what I am trying to do is move that house icon up a little without it unaligning everything else or switching everything else around.

I have tried

position:absolute and that just moves everything
I have tried line-height on the  link and same thing, moves everything

is it possible to the house icon up another way?

I will paste the link below

```
  <div id="container">

          <div id="box">
            <a href=""><img  src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/black/home-4-512.jpg" height="70" width"60" </a>
            <a href=""><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/arrow-back-512.png" height="90" width="90"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons/glossy-black-icons-business/080727-glossy-black-icon-business-computer-laptop2.png" height="100" width="100"></a>
          </div>
```

and my css

```
#container{
  margin:auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 1000px;

}

table{
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:30px;
}

.buttonMove{
    margin: 20px;
  margin-left: 294px;
}

#box{
  margin-left: 160px;
}

#box img{
  margin:0px 10px 0px 30px;
}

.house{
  position:absolute;
  left:502px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the image some bottom padding:

```
style="padding-bottom:10px"
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ximak)**

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
a img{ float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the other two images have a lot more vertical whitespace. The house is rendering at 70x70px while the other two icons are 90x90px. If you want a uniform solution, I would recommend editing the image to add the whitespace, or trimming the excess space of all of the images. Making those icons all the same dimensions should help you immensely.

Answer (score 0):

To target just the first img, use :first-child like so:

```
#box a:first-child img {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you have sized each image differently using the height and width tags in the code below. Thus you are struggling to balance all the images out.

The change I have made below to make **height** and **width** the same will solve your issue. One could of course be longer than the other but it is important to keep **height** the same for all the images and **width** the same for all the images.

```
<div id="box">
        <a href=""><img  src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/black/home-4-512.jpg" height="70" width"70" </a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/arrow-back-512.png" height="70" width="70"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons/glossy-black-icons-business/080727-glossy-black-icon-business-computer-laptop2.png" height="70" width="70"></a>
      </div>
```